# heterogeneous queries require ansi_warnings error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which has insert and update statements. The insert sometimes gets data bigger than defined column size for unknown columns.

I want to trim incoming record and insert them into the table.

When I am setting `ANSI_WARNING` to off in stored procedure and `ANSI_WARNING` on at end of procedure, still I am getting the same error while executing the procedure.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: are you using SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF statment in the beggining?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like below, then SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF will work

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(COL1 CHAR(8))


SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
    INSERT INTO #TEMP SELECT 'ABCDEFGHI'
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON

SELECT * FROM #TEMP
```